# PHP nested loop echos must not break into new line

Tags: php, line, echo, nested-loops, continuation

Here is my code segment:

```
for($i=0;$i<23;$i++){
    echo "<div id=slotshead></div>";
    for($j=0;$j<30;$j++) {
        echo " <div id=slots></div>";
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

But, it doesn't work. I want the two echo statements inside the loop to be continued, not break into a new line. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you dont want it to create new lines why do you have echo '<br>'?

Comment: Why are you applying the CSS to the H3 when that's what's wrapping all the block-level content within it? Further, you're explicitly putting a line-break after each `$i` loop... I'm completely lost on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want the two echos inside the loops to be joined as one line....

Comment: Just a side not, `id`s must be unique.

Comment: @DreamEater .... I cudn't get u...?

Comment: @MohammedZameer: Those `<div id=slotshead>`s and `<div id=slots>`s you're printing out...there will be 23 and 690 of each, respectively, with the same IDs.  A number of browsers will positively hate that, and you'll have a heck of a time trying to access the elements by ID.  You'll probably want to use classes instead of IDs here.

Comment: @cHao Thank you mate, I understood what IDs are..I changed it! ...thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have each looped output display in a single line, you were nearly there.

Add the following to CSS; and you're done.

```
h3 > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

It'll generate the output as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRKNa/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking... this will combine your loops:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 23; $i++) {
   echo "<div id=slotshead></div>";
   for ($j = 0; $j < 30; $j++) {
     echo " <div id=slots></div>";
   }
 }
 echo '<br>';
```

Comment: I need slothead to be at first.
e.g [slothead][slot][slot][slot][slot]<br>
    [slothead][slot][slot][slot][slot]

Comment: Edited and moved the `<br />` outside of the loops. What kind of output are you expecting? (Where should the `<br />`s be?)